# Date DataAnnotation validation attribute not working - shows the time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Not working. Date comes back from a database field. Shows as:

[image]

When it is not set from a database as there is no birth date, I get a little red dot top left. Shows as:

[image]

I don't want the time included. I have a data annotation display format but it does not seem to take affect.

My Model(not showing other fields) is:

```
   using System;
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

   namespace GbngWebClient.Models
   {
    public class UserProfileForMaintViewModel
    {
      // Can be null.
      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
      [RegularExpression(@"(((0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/((19|20)\d\d))$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid date format.")]
      public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
   }
  }
```

My view (not showing other fields) is:

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.UserProfileForMaintViewModel

<h1 class="page-header">User Profile Maintenance</h1>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "UserProfileMaint";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
 }

 @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateUserProfile", "UserProfiler", FormMethod.Post))
 {
  <div style="margin-top:10px;"></div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Your Profile</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "manadatory" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top:10px;"></div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-12">
                    @* Submit button. *@
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Would you consider using a separate view model for the view?

Comment: Not sure I  understand the question. I have other fields defined in that class that work fine. It's just the 1 DateTime field does not format as specified in the data annotation. Weird!

Comment: Datetime fields are always a hassle to deal with. So using a separate string field is a nice hack. If you are interested, i can give you an example

Comment: Sure send the example.

Answer (score 0):

From my previous experience I found out that it is much easier to deal with a string than a DateTime variable. So I usually use it as a hack. You can have an extra text field in your ViewModel and format it from the controller for the view -

```
public ActionResult Custom2()
{
    var profile = new Profile();
    profile.DoB = DateTime.Now.Date;
    profile.DoBText = profile.DoB.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return View(profile);
}
```

Now the view can accept the text data without any problem

```
@model mvcDeploymentTest.Models.Profile
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Custom2";
}

<h2>Custom2</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostTest", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DoBText, new { @class = "form-control", Type = "date" })

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

And once posted, you can parse the changed text value to datetime again with any formatting you want

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void PostTest(Profile myProfile)
 {
     DateTime dateValue;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myProfile.DoBText))
     {
         DateTime.TryParseExact(myProfile.DoBText,"yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
         myProfile.DoB = dateValue;
     }
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ApplyFormatInEditMode` is only used/applied when using `EditorFor` - you have to use the overload for `TextBoxFor` which accepts a format string in order to get a formatted output in the rendered `<input />`.

```cs
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

`{0:d}` will apply whatever short date format matches your app's culture settings. Replace that with a custom format string if you want something else.

If you want to use your browser's native date input (`<input type="date" />`), you'll need to use an ISO-8601 short date, which is `YYYY-MM-DD`. An example:

```cs
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" })
```

The default modelbinder knows how to transform that into a DateTime object, which you can then format into whatever else you wanted/needed.